# Listings - How to extend the indentation of lines

Tags: listings

Is there an opportunity to extend the indentation of lines in a listing?

My MWE looks like that:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}
public class Foo{
 Object obj;

 void method() {
  // do anything
  {
   // do another thin
  }
 }
}
\end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The indentation I used here is only one space. Is there an opportunity to extend each space before the beginning of text by for example four spaces?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you want to add a fixed amount of space before each line of the listing, or add space according to the number of spaces that appear at the start of each line?

Comment: Good question. I want to add space according to the number of spaces!

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer since it seems to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
Normal text   
\begin{lstlisting}[xleftmargin=4em]
public class Foo{
 Object obj;

 void method() {
  // do anything
  {
   // do another thin
  }
 }
}
\end{lstlisting}
More mormal text 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But is there a way to add space according to the number of leading spaces?

Comment: Isn't there a way to realize my question from the comment above?

Comment: @mrbela If you do mean add one space if there are one leading space, two spaces if there are two leading spaces, and so, I do not kow any method with LateX.  I Think that the best option then is try to find a external tool able to search and replace leading spaces in source files.